# Swift 4 how to test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I have migrated my app from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and I am getting the above message. I have gone to Build Settings and checked that Swift 3 `@objc` inference is set to On and run my app. But nothing appears in the debugger pane at the bottom of Xcode. I am therefore not clear how I am to locate the offending code.
In other words, am I testing incorrectly?
Or could it be that there are no faults and I should switch Swift 3 `@objc` inference to default? If I do that no warnings show up.

Comment: Test **everything**, especially all UI and KVC/KVO related functions. If no error occurs, switch the @objc build setting to default. Due to the Cocoa bindings abilities macOS is more sensitive than iOS.

Comment: What does KVC/KVO mean?

Comment: Key-Value Coding / Key-Value Observing which is heavily using Objective-C under the hood.

Comment: I am just about to test my app. However, am I right in thinking that this warning shows up whether there are any faults or not? In other words, it is telling you to test your app but not saying there are any faults?

Comment: @vadian I have tried setting the `@obj-c inference` build setting to both `off` and `default`, but none make the warning go away. Maybe you could be specific in how to test any code in Xcode?

Comment: @Andreas Issues are displayed in the console. Resolve the issues by adding `@objc` to the affected properties / functions. Since the issues occur at runtime you have to test / run everything. If no issues are displayed anymore set the build setting of the target to `default`.

Comment: @vadian My project runs perfectly with the inference off. Only one class inherits from Objective-C, the app delegate. I don't use any Cocoa UI items. If so, the inference is in the Metal and MTK code, and that's all tested. I do use an autoreleasepool, if that might be troubling. I do have a custom NSWindow. All code is tested.